# Travelling on my UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, jamaican-citizens

I was granted a 6 months visa to the Uk but Have been working a lot and also my grandma died  in February so i had to go to the US for a few weeks then I came back and went back to the US again, but I want to travel to the UK before my UK visa expires on June 11th basically a month a away from now, do u think I would be allowed to enter in the country?

I am from Jamaica.

Comment: Did you visit the UK with this visa already? And is it a single entry or multiple entry visa?

Answer (score 1):

This is covered explicitly in Paragraph 20A of the [Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423556/20150424_immigration_rules_part_1_final.pdf), which says...

> Leave to enter or remain in the United Kingdom will usually lapse on
>   the holder going to a country or territory outside the common travel
>   area. However, under article 13 of the Immigration (Leave to Enter and
>   Remain) Order 2000 such leave will not lapse where it was given for a
>   period exceeding six months or where it was conferred by means of an
>   entry clearance (other than a visit visa).

As a Jamaican, you would have an entry clearance and as long as it is designated as 'multiple entry' you're ok.  You can tell if your visa is multiple entry if there's a "MULT" in the common format area (i.e., near the top).